# C++11 and static library that is linked against libstdc++

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++, libc++

I have a library which is a static library for C and C++.
The problem is that the library is linked against `libstdc++`.

In Xcode when I switch to `libc++` (to use C++11 features and use the mentioned C++ library) it throws many compile errors.

The authors of the library say that the library is not ready for C++11.

Is there still a way to use both?

Answer (score 0):

Your 3-rd party static library should be linked against the same version of the C++ library it was compiled against. This includes not only the type of library (libstdc++), but also major/minor version numbers to ensure ABI compatibility. Any different library version would get you either build breaks in best case, or weird crashes in worst case. Read more about ABI versioning in [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html).

If the interface for 3-rd party library only has [POD types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure), you can make a shared library out of your static library, and then use it from your app linked with libc++.